# Extend ruby compiler on the fly

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I've met interesting ruby gems [vernacular](https://github.com/kddeisz/vernacular) and [vernacular-ast](https://github.com/kddeisz/vernacular-ast).

By these gems we can extend the ruby compiler, add new syntax etc.

From the code I understood that I have to run manually on ruby lines or ruby files:

```
require 'vernacular'

Vernacular.configure {}

Vernacular.modify('my ruby code goes here')
```

Is it possible to add `Vernacular` to my project so I can use extended syntax?

Something like this:

```
# my_ruby_file.rb
require 'vernacular'
require 'extended_syntax'

extended_syntax arg1, arg2
```